# Multicol* in Beamer

Tags: vertical-alignment, multicol, beamerposter

I'm aware that you can't really use the starred version of multicol in Beamer due to the fact that Beamer typesets things in a box. However, is there another way to force multicol to not balance the columns in Beamer? I would prefer to keep using multicol if at all possible.

Edit: I'm using beamer to make a research poster, so I would like to avoid setting break points manually.

Comment: Are you using beamer or beamerposter?  See http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamerposter

Comment: @JohnKormylo  beamerposter

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example (MWE) to clarify your question and help people to help you. It will reduce the time and effort people put into answers which turn out not to work for you at all. (There's already been one of those.)